# Use cookie with cross domain ajax call

Tags: javascript, ajax, cookies

I must use cross domain ajax,while the sever config which I cannot change is

`Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*`

when I set `withCredentials = true` to use ajax with cookie , I will get an error:

> Cannot use wildcard in Access-Control-Allow-Origin when credentials flag is true.

when I set

> setRequestHeader("Cookie", value)

an error occur either

> Refused to set unsafe header "Cookie"

is there any other ways to use ajax with cookie?

Answer (score 0):

Ask whoever has access, to change the * to $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'].